# Get function URL's using AZ PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

In PowerShell, I'm attempting to retrieve the invocation URL and key for a Function App. After several hours of trying to do just that, I've hit a brick wall in relation to the invocation URL. Is this actually possible?

As Microsoft haven't bothered to provide an equivalent to `az rest`, I've been looking at [`Invoke-AzResourceAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/invoke-azresourceaction?view=azps-4.3.0), the documentation for which reads as follows -

> The Invoke-AzResourceAction cmdlet invokes an action on a specified Azure resource. To get a list of supported actions, use the Azure Resource Explorer tool.

After sometime using the [Azure Resource Explorer tool](https://resources.azure.com) I realised that it was not really very helpful, so I started looking for other options and found [`Get-AzProviderOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azprovideroperation?view=azps-4.3.0)

> The Get-AzProviderOperation gets the operations exposed by Azure resource providers.

Using the above command I can see that there are three available operations -

```
Operation                                        OperationName                   ProviderNamespace  ResourceName       Description            IsDataAction
---------                                        -------------                   -----------------  ------------       -----------            ------------
microsoft.web/sites/functions/action             Functions Web Apps              Microsoft Web Apps Web App            Functions Web Apps.           False
microsoft.web/sites/functions/listsecrets/action List Web Apps Functions Secrets Microsoft Web Apps Web Apps Functions List Function secrets.        False
microsoft.web/sites/functions/listkeys/action    List Web Apps Functions Keys    Microsoft Web Apps Web Apps Functions List Function keys.           False
```

## First attempt

Initially I was happy using the `listsecrets` action, but after adding a function with a custom route to my Function App I noticed that `listsecrets` does not honour this custom route in the `trigger_url` property, so I had to abandon use of it.

```
$functionApp = Get-AzWebAppSlot -Name $FunctionAppName -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -Slot $Slot
$functionApp | Format-List
$functionKey = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId ("{0}/functions/{1}" -f $functionApp.Id, $FunctionName) -Action "listsecrets" -ApiVersion "2019-08-01" -Force
```

## Second attempt

Next I tried to use the `listkeys` action to get the function key, in conjunction with `functions` action. I know for the REST API that the invocation URL can be found at `properties.invoke_url_template` when querying a function, so I was hoping for the same here. Alas...

Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId ("{0}/functions" -f $functionApp.Id) -Action $FunctionName -ApiVersion "2019-08-01" -Force

> No route registered for '/api/functions/Health?api-version=2019-08-01'

It's quite possible I'm implementing `Invoke-AzResourceAction` incorrectly in this case (never used it prior to today).

## Other things I've thought about

In addition to lacking an equivalent to `az rest`, AZ PowerShell also lacks an equivalent to `az-account-get-access-token`. This means that I can't grab my token and simply query the REST API.

Comment: So, in short, you want to get the function url, include the function key, like in https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oEyy.png ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, if you want to get the function(trigger) url, including the function key, you could use the command below, the `$FunctionURL` is what you want.

```
$FunctionAppName = "joyfun"
$GroupName = "xxxxx"
$TriggerName = "HttpTrigger1"
$FunctionApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $GroupName -Name $FunctionAppName
$Id = $FunctionApp.Id
$DefaultHostName = $FunctionApp.DefaultHostName
$FunctionKey = (Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId "$Id/functions/$TriggerName" -Action listkeys -Force).default
$FunctionURL = "https://" + $DefaultHostName + "/api/" + $TriggerName + "?code=" + $FunctionKey
```

[image]

If the trigger is in a slot, change this line
`$FunctionApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $GroupName -Name $FunctionAppName` to `$FunctionApp = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $GroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -Slot <slotname>`.

[image]

**Update:**

I test the custom route on my side, my `host.json` snippet is like below.

```
{
  "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": "api/Health",
        }
    }
}
```

You could use the command below.

```
$FunctionAppName = "joyfun"
$GroupName = "xxxxx"
$TriggerName = "HttpTrigger1"
$FunctionApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $GroupName -Name $FunctionAppName
$Id = $FunctionApp.Id
$DefaultHostName = $FunctionApp.DefaultHostName
$FunctionKey = (Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceId "$Id/functions/$TriggerName" -Action listkeys -Force).default
$invokeurl = (Get-AzResource -ResourceId "$Id/functions" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$FunctionAppName/$TriggerName"}).Properties.invoke_url_template
$FunctionURL = $invokeurl + "?code=" + $FunctionKey
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is that with custom routes, the value of `$TriggerName` will differ from the actual function name. That's exactly why I can't just use the `listsecrets` action and take the `trigger_url` property.

Comment: Yes, that does work, thank you. It's odd - even though the `Get-AzResource` doesn't output the `properties` object, you can reference it. In the end, all I needed was `(Get-AzResource -ResourceId ("{0}/functions/{1}" -f $FunctionAppName.Id, $TriggerName)).Properties.invoke_url_template`.